# How to get the list of all props of all compositional hierarchy in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have multiple layers of composition:

```
const ComponentA = ({ firstProp, secondProp }) => {
    reutrn <div>Component A</div>
}

const ComponentB = ({ thirdProp, fourthProp }) => {
    reutrn <ComponentA
         firstProp='first prop'
         secondProp='second prop'
    />
}

const ComponentC = ({ fifthProp }) => {
    return <ComponentB
         thirdProp='third prop'
         fourthProp='fourth prop'
    />
}
```

Now I have given an instance of `ComponentC` and I want to access all of the props in the compositional hierarchy.

How can I do that?

**Update**

To clarify more, I'm talking about reflection.

I have been given an instance of `ComponentC` and I want to find out its props using `componentCInstance.props` and then find out the props of the `ComponentB` from that `componentCInstance` etc.

Comment: don't destruct like `{ }` just pass `props` as parameter and use as `props.firstProps`

Comment: I answered your question assuming that you need to use firstProp in ComponentC. But you could clarify your use case by adding more code to your question. Do you really need the firstProp in ComponentC? Or just want to see all props in developer mode?

Comment: Well, there is a way. You could call `ComponentC` like a custom hook as described [here](https://dev.to/teetotum/react-dark-magic-devour-your-children-4j90) and then access the props of the children and those of the children-of-children (`renderResult.props.children`). But this would mean that your code is tied to the composition of sub-components, so this is usually a bad idea. What's your use-case?

Comment: @Martin, I have a component being delivered to me that has a prop called `superAdmin` and I need to see if it exists or not. If it exists, I should check the user role and based on that render the component or not.

Comment: If you absolutely have no way of changing the information structure you receive (e.g. adding some config object that exposes `superAdmin`) then I propose you wrap what you receive in a `SuperSpecialPropExtractor_HereBeDragons_BeCareful_Component` that does indeed internally call the render function explicitly and accesses the result to read out the props. Be aware that all `rules of hook` apply.
But this is really only a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't access all props at Component C this way.

Solution 1: If Component C is the source of all props, you need to define them there, and pass down the component tree

Solution 2: If your hierarchy is too long, consider using Context (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).

Solution 3: If your props are independent from Component C and are part of application state, consider using a state management tool (for example https://redux.js.org/)